# Can't update the database from an EF model in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2022, datamodel

I am trying to update a SQL Server database from an Entity Framework model in Visual Studio 2022. The model was generated in Visual Studio from the same SQL Server and database.

I get the error message:

> IsDocumentInProject must be called on the UI thread.

I am on Windows 10 and both Windows and Visual Studio are patched to the latest versions.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have this error too, any solution?

Comment: I havnt found anything yet